# Windows - PyAudio and PortAudio do not work even after they were installed

Tags: python, conda, pyaudio, portaudio

I'm trying to make a voice-chat program, trying to use PyAudio since it is one of the more popular modules to work with when you try to make a voice chat program, plus more sources if I'll need help. Tried to download PyAudio with PipWin, tried to run it and it gave me the error message:

```
import _portaudio as pa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_portaudio'
```

Now I downloaded the PortAudio tgz file from the download website and extracted it, but I cant seem to see how to make it work out with pyAudio. Also tried to use conda to install PyAudio but I can't seem to find where it put the file in, even when I search in the Anaconda3 folder.
I use Windows.

Did anyone have the same problem and if so how did you solve it?

Comment: Simplest implication is that the module is not installed at correct location. how did you check if the module is correctly installed? can you share the output/snapshot of that

Comment: what do you mean? I put the PortAudio folder in the python39/lib, and same with PyAudio.py.